# How to call if file exists by ID

Tags: php, file, validation, exists

i have file in /pdf/**0001_test.pdf**

0001 is "id", and "test.pdf" is a file.
how to call the "id" based on this "if file exists" code

```
<?php
$filename = "pdf/0001_test.pdf";
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "File exist.";
} else {
    echo "File does not exist.";
}
?>
```

Comment: you want to call fileExists by dynamic Id with file name? How to call means what? Do you want to open file?

Comment: @NavnathJadhav yes sir call fileExists by dynamic id, but not open that file, only show on table that the file exist or not.

Comment: do you want to open pdf and show it in the table? share your full existing HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  $file = "test.pdf";
  $filename = "pdf/".$d['id']."_".$file;
  if (file_exists($filename)) {
      echo "<p>".$fileName." exists.</p>";
  } else {
      echo "<p>".$fileName." not exists.</p>";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my full code sir

```
<table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>NO</th>
            <th>Nama</th>
            <th>NIM</th>
            <th>PDF FILE</th>
            <th>OPSI</th>
        </tr>
        <?php 
        include 'koneksi.php';
        $no = 1;
        $data = mysqli_query($koneksi,"select * from file");
        while($d = mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $no++; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $d['nama']; ?></td>
                <td><a href="pdf/<?php echo $d['pdf']; ?>" target="_blank">
                <b>
                    <?php
                        $filename = "pdf/0001_test.pdf";
                            if (file_exists($filename)) {
                                echo "File exist.";
                                } else {
                                echo "File does not exist.";
                                }
                    ?>
                </b>
                </td>
                <td><?php echo $d['alamat']; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $d['id']; ?>">EDIT</a>
                    <a href="hapus.php?id=<?php echo $d['id']; ?>">HAPUS</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php 
        }
        ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: Check this   `<?php
$id = 001;
$file = "test.pdf";
$filename = "pdf/".$id."_".$file;
if (file_exists($filename)) {
 echo '<iframe src=".$filename." width="500" height="500"></iframe>';
} else {
    echo $fileName." not exists.";
}
?>`

Comment: You need to use I frame to open pdf file.

Comment: how to dynamic this code **$id = 001;** sir

there are many "id" in my table

Comment: what is in `$d['pdf']`? I think you can use `$d['id']`. If your id is in `$d['id']`. You can use `$filename = "pdf/".$d['id']."_".$file;`

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: yes this is working, thank you sir, love you haha
this is the full code, i dont want to open pdf, just validation that pdf's are exists or not

<?php 
$id= $d['id'];
$file = "test.pdf";
$filename = "pdf/".$d['id']."_".$file; 
if (file_exists($filename)) {  
echo 'Exists'; } 
else {     echo $fileName." not exists."; } 
?>

thank you @NavnathJadhav

Comment: how to give you reputation for this answer sir?